# Query to retrieve data using two foreign keys

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I'm working on a football statistics database, and in the table to store results of matches, I have two references to the primary key of a team table: one home, one away.

My intention is to create a query which returns the name of both of the teams, along with other details, but I can't think of a way to achieve this WITH the team names (my attempts so far can only produce one team name, with the other an ID number). I'll give the relation structure if this wasn't clear:

(PKs in bold, FKs asterisk)

team(**team_id**, team_name, venue)

match(**match_id**, home_team*, away_team*, home_score, away_score, date,)

My desired output would be a table with these columns:

home_team_name, home_team_score, away_team_score, away_team_name, date, venue

Is this possible with my tables, or should I change the way I store results?

Answer (score 0):

When joining the team table to the match table in a query, you'll need to join the match table to the team table twice. You need to use an different alias for the teams each time.